# What are the Star Trek technologies that enabled humans to stop working for a living?

Tags: star-trek

All the humans I know around me offline and online would like to stop working and start living. It is fascinating the Star Trek economy has made this achievement. What are the Star Trek technologies that gave humans this luxury?

I think it may be a good idea to email a list of Star Trek technologies that made it so to the Elon Musks on Earth today and request that they start work right away.

Comment: Two words. Replicators.

Comment: @Volarum, I have doubts about replicators being the enabling technology. Please see my new question.
http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154490/if-replicators-allowed-humans-to-stop-working-why-were-replicators-shut-down-in

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Federation has fusion power and replicators - these technologies put them into what is called a post-scarcity society. They have abundant energy and the ability to convert that energy into food and materials.

Starship impulse engine are fusion powered.

A starship also has a warp core, which usually has more than enough capacity to move the ship and power ship systems. Think along the lines of modern nuclear powered submarines - they have enough residual power after propulsion to power most electrical systems including air conditioning.

The federation even has gigantic industrial replicators capable of creating rather large and complex items.

And I'm pretty sure Elon Musk (and quite a few others) are already working on these technologies.

Comment: are there robots that do dirty jobs like cleaning? what would a restaurant look like: would there still be servers because that is part of the experience but the tables automatically bussed and set? No one washing dishes (a very unpleasant job in a busy restaurant) in back?